# Swagger UI page showing invalid image

Tags: spring-boot, docker, dockerfile, swagger-ui, azure-aks

Swagger UI is showing below node image at bottom of the page. Why ? How this can be removed or hidden.
We are using spring boot rest api.

```
 <span style="float: right;"><a target="_blank" href="https://online.swagger.io/validator/debug?url=<some DNS>/swagger/api-docs?group={some group info}"><img alt="Online validator badge" src="https://online.swagger.io/validator?url=<some DNS>/swagger/api-docs?group={some group info}"></a></span>
```

[image]

Getting this image after deploying docker into Azure Kubernetes Cluster. when I run an application on local hot then I don't get this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling validator using below code worked for me.

```
@Bean
    UiConfiguration uiConfig() {
        return UiConfigurationBuilder.builder()
            .displayRequestDuration(true)
            .validatorUrl(null)
            .build();
    }
```